# Parenthesis Checker Implementing Stack

Tags: java

So I'm suppose to be taking in a user inputted .java file and checking if the file's brackets, parenthesis, and curly braces are balanced. And outputting "balanced' and if not "not balanced' i have the code all written out but my stackBalance method isn't checking properly. I'm told it is returning the "balance" output after any match. The loop should continue until there is nothing to parse and the stack is not empty. Basically my program is deciding "balanced" too quickly (before checking the entire stack). But i'm just not seeing where I messed up. A quick fix would be appreciated! Here's the code:

```
    public static String stackBalance(Scanner in){
        if(!in.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Nothing to see");
            }
        else{
            stack<Character> stack = new stack<Character>();
            Boolean istrue = true;
            String expr = in.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < expr.length(); i++)
               {
                   char c = expr.charAt(i);
                   if (c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{')
                   {
                       stack.push(c);
                   }
                   if (c == '}' || c == ')' || c == ']')
                   {
                       if (stack.isEmpty())
                           istrue = false;

                       char last = stack.peek();
                       if (c == '}' && last == '{' || c == ')' && last == '(' || c == ']' && last == '[')
                           stack.pop();
                       else 
                           istrue = false;
                   }

               }
            if (istrue)
              {
                  System.out.println("File is balanced");
              }
               else
                   System.out.println("File is not balanced");


                }
            return null;

        }


   }
```

Comment: Awful, unreadable style.  A quick turn in a debugger would have told you where you went wrong faster than asking here.

Comment: The first time you detect unbalanced brackets or parentheses, you don't have to keep on checking. Also, a name like `istrue` is really not very descriptive, it doesn't really say what the variable is used for, the semantics of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not decide too soon, it is *not* decided correctly when everything is over.

To see what's going on consider this expression:

```
((x+y)
```

Your program will return `true`, even though the parentheses are clearly unbalanced. This is because the condition for balanced needs to include the check that the stack has been emptied:

```
if (istrue && stack.isEmpty()) {
    ... // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
} else {
    ...
}
```